# HQL can't handle parentheses after FROM

Tags: hibernate, hql

I'm trying to count the rows of a complicated call I have, such as ...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT *my complicated HQL table request here* )
```

Unfortunately hibernate parser complains about the 'FROM (' part.

Any suggestions, on how to bypass this issue?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a HQL or native SQL query?

Comment: @Piotr yes curently Im bypassing my problem by going the native SQL route, but idealy Im trying to have my HQL spit out SELECT COUNT(*) col1 FROM ( SELECT *my complicated table SQL* )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

to use a hql query you need a mapped entities in java pojo, in that case you actually don't have any, anyway if you need to count the results then you can

```
select count(id) from your entities  where your complicated restrictions here
```

if you do it like that, hibernate will generate a SQL query ,very similar that you wrote

Comment: thx I think that's the way to go; my problem though is that *my complicated restictions* has a GROUP BY that would need my id to be MAX(id) instead to work. And of coure this comes out as an "unexpected token: MAX" exception

Comment: select count(id) from your entities  where your complicated restrictions here group by id having id=(select max(id) from your entities)

Comment: thanks the SELECT in the restriction works, but it unfortunately changes my query quite a bit, due to my large table it increases the load/time x2/x30. I'll validate this answer if nothing more efficient gets suggested

Comment: what about split in two query one for get the max id and another for the count, maybe that it is a bit faster

Answer (score 1):

Why are you creating a subquery in this case? Do you really need it?

If this is really supposed to be a HQL query as you mention in the title (and not a native query), than according to [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html):

> Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the **select** or **where**
>   clauses.

Comment: thx, for the answer I realise now that my naive attempt was wrong. But this still doesn't give me a way on how to go on about doing it.

Comment: And are you sure you can't transform your query to achieve what you want without subquery in the FROM clause?

Comment: Ok will look in that direction